# How to Fix CloudFormation error "Provided Load Balancers may not be valid. Please ensure they exist and try again

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

when I try to create Autoscale group with Application load balancer with the following cloudformation yml file

```java
    LoadBalancer: 
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
      Properties: 
        Type: application
        Subnets: 
          Ref: VPCZoneIdentifier  

    AutoScalingGroup:
      Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
      DependsOn: LoadBalancer
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZones: 
          Ref: "AvailabilityZones"
        Cooldown: 120
        DesiredCapacity:
          Ref: DesiredCapacityASG
        LaunchConfigurationName: 
          Ref: LaunchConfiguration
        MaxSize:
          Ref: MaxSizeASG
        MinSize:
          Ref: MinSizeASG
        LoadBalancerNames: 
          - Ref: "LoadBalancer"
        TargetGroupARNs:
          - !Ref TargetGroup
```

I got an error saying "Provided Load Balancers may not be valid. Please ensure they exist and try again. (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID:)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this error is happening because you used **LoadBalancerNames** for Application loadbalancer as it is noted [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-loadbalancernames)

to fix it : remove the  **LoadBalancerNames** and keep **TargetGroupARNs** in the properties

<strike>LoadBalancerNames: 

    - Ref: "LoadBalancer"</strike>

so the yml file will be like :

```java
    AutoScalingGroup:
      Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
      DependsOn: LoadBalancer
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZones: 
          Ref: "AvailabilityZones"
        Cooldown: 120
        DesiredCapacity:
          Ref: DesiredCapacityASG
        LaunchConfigurationName: 
          Ref: LaunchConfiguration
        MaxSize:
          Ref: MaxSizeASG
        MinSize:
          Ref: MinSizeASG
        TargetGroupARNs:
          - !Ref TargetGroup
```

Comment: It should be list of string. so it will be like - [ !Ref  TargetGroup ]

Comment: @KavyeshShah it shouldn't be `[ !Ref TargetGroup ] ` as it's a yml file, the `-` already denotes list so, square brackets aren't necessary but in JSON they are

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ansible `ec2_asg` module and reached here, replace `load_balancers:` with `target_group_arns` and pass the ARN of the Target Group.